# Use SNI with pip/pypi on Ubuntu 14 Trusty

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-14.04, pip

`pip` no longer works on old versions of Python 2, because https://pypi.python.org/ now requires Server Name Indication (SNI), which isn't available in Python 2.7.6, the version of Python that comes with Ubuntu 14 Trusty.

https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978 explains:

> Upgrading to the last Python 2.7 release is an option.
>
> However, note that Python 2.7 series itself is now End of Life and support in pip was dropped with version 21.0.

I'm maintaining a legacy code base; I need to pursue the least invasive option possible to get `pip` working again. What are my options? What's the smallest possible change I can make to get back to (temporarily) working order?